Getting access to module internals
I have successfully installed minikanren in Racket. The module starts like this:
#lang racket/base

(provide succeed fail
         == fresh conde condi run run*
         conda condu project)

In my own module, I include:
#lang racket

(require minikanren)
(require (rename-in rackunit [fail rackunit-fail]))

I'm currently exploring minikanren in Racket and want to experiment with all the functions and syntax defined in the minikanren module. Specifically, I’d like to call functions like unify and understand the process of defining relations, so having access to syntax like lambdag@ would be helpful.
I know that when I run minikanren.rkt, I enter a REPL where I can use these internal functions directly. However, my goal is to have a module of my own where I can write code, run it, and have access to my definitions as well as key functions like unify and lambdag@.
Is there a way to achieve this without copying the entire contents of minikanren.rkt into my module?

The whole point of modules is encapsulation and control over what's exported.
